# Process X number of records from DataTable in a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have a datatable which contains a `X` number of records. 
I am sending these records into a remote database using SqlBulkCopy. Each record contains a big blob so the transfer is very slow, therefore, I'm want to send each bulk containing only 10 records.

What I have at the moment uploads the first record, then uploads in sets of 10 but omits the remaing records. The problem is that my loop is wrong. It should process the records from `0-10`, `11-20`, etc.

Any ideas?

```
For Each iRow As DataRow In dtSortedDataTable.Rows
dtToUpload.ImportRow(dtSortedDataTable.Rows(dtSortedDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(iRow)))
If iCurrent Mod 10 = 0 Then
    'Call function SqlBulkCopy to upload 10 records existing in the dtToUpload
End If
iCurrent += 1
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues here:

1. Assuming iCurrent starts at 0, to get the behavior you want you need to add one to iCurrent:

   ```
   If (iCurrent + 1) Mod 10 = 0 Then
   ```
2. Your stated ranges are incorrect based on the logic you are trying to implement. You want to process 0-9, 10-19, etc.
3. Don't forget to add a bulk copy upload after the loop or check to see if iCurrent is the last item you are processing:

   ```
   If (iCurrent + 1) Mod 10 = 0 OrElse (iCurrent = dtSortedDataTable.Rows.Count - 1) Then
   ```

Comment: How do I get the last index there?

Comment: Updated answer to include use of the datatable's rows to determine when you are done.